# Read only connection for an admin extension

Tags: extensions, magento-1.6

I'm just adding the clean reports community extension to my site and very useful it is (Thanks Kalen Jordan et al) 
https://github.com/kalenjordan/custom-reports

Part of the docs sensibly suggest limiting this to a read only connection to prevent sql injection should anyone get into the admin area, but i'm just not sure how to do that. I'm aware of the config resources section with the _read, and i can see that this extension allows configuration of a named connection - the helper method that gets the connection reads

```
    $resource       = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connectionName = Mage::getStoreConfig('reports/cleansql/default_connection');
    if (!$connectionName) {
        $connectionName = 'core_read';
    }
    return $resource->getConnection($connectionName);
```

My questions are, is core_read automatically read only? if not how do i setup an additional connection that is genuinely read only, i assume using a different mysql role?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this may help...

**Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getConnection($name)** gets the connection details via this method call...
**$connConfig = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig($name);**

In your instance the $name is "core_read".

The **getResourceConnectionConfig($name)** method returns **$this->_xml->global->resources->{$name};** in **Mage_Core_Model_Config**.

**_xml->global->resources->core_read** is found in "app/etc/config.xml" and contains the following XML...

```
<core_read>
    <connection>
        <use>default_read</use>
    </connection>
</core_read>
```

As far as I can tell this then uses the "default_read" config node that, from the same file, contains...

```
<default_read>
    <connection>
        <use>default_setup</use>
    </connection>
</default_read>
```

That then uses the "default_setup" node that is overridden in your local.xml file.

So, if that is correct you *should* be able to create a new MySQL account with read only access then just copy and paste the "default_setup" node in your local.xml file, change the node name to "default_read" and the username / password to your new read only account you just created in MySQL.

Completely untested thou! And I am assuming that core_read is actually used as a read only account by Magento.

Since by default it looks like core_read and core_write always just default to the default_setup details in your local.xml it could be that core_read connections may write to the database in core code or 3rd party modules.

Comment: Just to confirm, the "use" node does indeed do as expected.

See **Mage_Core_Model_Config::getResourceConnectionConfig($name)**

Comment: Thanks for that, makes complete sense now its pointed out. Good point about core code possibly using that connection to write by mistake at some point though

Comment: What occurs to me is that i can set up a new one e.g. extension_read or read_restricted and use that instead. Thanks for setting the seed

Comment: Yep, that would work really well!